# Why can Rebol repeat not take a literal word type of value

Tags: rebol, rebol3

The Rebol function *set* accepts an **any-word!** but *repeat* only accepts **word!**

Is there a particular reason that *repeat* could not also accept a *lit-word!* ?

Answer (score 1):

`repeat` uses same syntax as `foreach` and similar functions. They all accept **word!** only. I guess there's no particular reason, it's just what people are used to.

Answer (score 1):

*lit-word!* params can be a bit confusing. That is, when the param is a *lit-word!*, you're saying "don't evaluate it", so passing a *word!* means the func is already seeing it as a *lit-word!*.

R3 only supports *word!* args in *foreach* as well, which is more consistent. Things look much cleaner this way, and are the best model when you write your own control funcs and such.